# Send ssh commands with a script

Tags: networking, scripting, ssh, ksh

I want to to check a Nortel Router by running ./script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
print "IP:"
read ip;
ping ${ip};
ssh -l default ${ip} "sho mod; en; sho int; sho node-e; sho node-a";
```

I can ssh normaly with 
    ssh -l [user] [ip].

But not with 
    ssh -l [user] [ip] '[cmd1], [cmd2]' it says automatically "Conection to [ip] closed."

Comment: What if you leave the commands off of the end? Does the ssh complete successfully then?

Comment: How are you sending in the password when you run the script? Or are you using `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` (or similar). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's application called `expect` which can do that kind of interaction / terminal simulation for you. Otherwise, you could write a script using `fabric` or even straight in python using [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)

Running commands this way would be better of course, but if your router doesn't accept commands this way, you'll need to simulate the standard connection.

Comment: The problem here is most likely your router as I tried your commands out. I would suggest going to Nortel's website and asking there about that specific issue.